# How to count how many times a value appears in a list based on another column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this sample table

| City | Store |
| --- | --- |
| City1 | STORE1 |
| City1 | STORE2 |
| City1 | STORE3 |
| City2 | STORE4 |
| City3 | STORE5 |
| City3 | STORE6 |
| City3 | STORE7 |
| City4 | STORE8 |

I want to show a card that will tell me how many stores are present in the table in a city.
For example, if I have a slicer and I pick Store1, the card should read 1 of 3 because it's 1 store of a 3 within the same city.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following measure

```
_count:=
COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ) & " " & "of" & " "
    & CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[city] ) )
```

[image: SOlution]